# Mediawiki doesn't send any email

Tags: php, email, mediawiki, sendmail

My Mediawiki installation (1.28.0, PHP 7.0.13) doesn't send any email and yet there is no error reported. I checked using Special:EmailUser page.

What I have tryed:

1) Command line SendMail can send email without problem.

2) A simple PHP script to send a mail using PHP's mail() function. It works.

3) I have turned PHP mail log. There is a normal log line for each Mediawiki email "sent", but nothing is actually sent.

Additional info:

PHP is configured (correctly since it works) to send email using Linux SendMail. MediaWiki is not configured to use direct SMTP.

Any suggestion apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd add extra debug logging before https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/7381d956c6e75385c4d9625439cd64119f883268/includes/mail/UserMailer.php#L411 to collect all the parameters and reproduce it in isolation.

Comment: any chance that you're running wiki on hosting with some kind of spam filter activated and your outgoing mediawiki emails are blocked ?

Comment: @Alex: Will do.

Comment: @wakalaka: no, there is nothing filtering whatever.

Comment: @Alex. As you suggested, I turned Mediakiki debug log on, and added a few lines just before the line you pointed so that I captured all the arguments values passed to the mail() function. Then in my TestEmail.php script I put those value exactly. and it works! So I don't understand why a call to mail() from Mediawiki source code does nothing (no mail sent, no error) and the same call to mail() called from a basic PHP script correctly send the expected email.

Comment: Is it possible that the call to mail() I see in Mediawiki source code (https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/7381d956c6e75385c4d9625439cd64119f883268/includes/mail/UserMailer.php#L411) is not the standard PHP mail() function?

Comment: A mystery? It is the plain old php [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). php.ini defines which transport it is using and it may be the case that cli config differs from the apache/fpm config.  Very unlikely but it might be user permissions, i.e. web server user (www-data, httpd, etc) has some special restrictions comparing to the shell user. Try your test script via browser. If it still sends the email, the only option I see is hardcore debugging using tcpdump, strace and other delicious things from low-level toolbox. Or try it on another OS. Which one you are using?

Comment: @Alex, the test I made was a PHP script used from the webserver running the wiki, using the browser, not from cli. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Well, something must be different. Since no obvious guesses helped, `tcpdump -i <eth1> -s 65535 -w mails.pcap 'port 25'` =(

Comment: @Alex,tcpdump helped me a lot. I was able to see that the email sent my the wiki was perfectly sent. If you want to rewrite your comments (Debuggng and tcpdump) as solution, I will be glad to mark it as the right solution.

Comment: @Wakalaka: you were absolutely right. There was a filter somewhere I had completely overlooked. That filter caught the email sent from wikiùedia but not the email sent by my simple PHP test function.

Comment: @fpiette hooray :)

Comment: The answer can be found in [this very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885067/mediawiki-doesnt-send-any-email).